# Compress pandas dataframe based on column name and last non-NaN value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the following:

```
col1 col2 x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 
a    b    0.3 0.2 NaN NaN
c    d    0.4 0.3 0.2 NaN
e    f    0.2 0.1 NaN NaN
v    x    NaN 0.2 NaN NaN
x    r    NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

What I'd like to do is for each row find the right-most numeric value, and restructure the dataframe with a two new columns, the first containing the column name and the second the rightmost value, like so:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
a    b    x_2  0.2
c    d    x_3  0.2
e    f    x_2  0.1
v    x    x_2  0.2
x    r    None None
```

Is there an easy way to do this, perhaps using `pandas.apply`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to melt the DataFrame to make it long instead of wide grouping by col1 and col2 and taking the last non-NaN values:

```
with_value = pd.melt(
    df, 
    id_vars = ['col1', 'col2'], 
    var_name='col3', 
    value_name='col4'
).dropna()
```

Which gives you:

```
   col1 col2 col3  col4
0     a    b  x_1   0.3
1     c    d  x_1   0.4
2     e    f  x_1   0.2
5     a    b  x_2   0.2
6     c    d  x_2   0.3
7     e    f  x_2   0.1
8     v    x  x_2   0.2
11    c    d  x_3   0.2
```

Then group and take the last value...

```
last_value = with_value.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).last()
```

Which gives you:

```
          col3  col4
col1 col2           
a    b     x_2   0.2
c    d     x_3   0.2
e    f     x_2   0.1
v    x     x_2   0.2
```

Then reindex and drop the index to get what you want, eg:

```
final = last_value.reindex([df.col1, df.col2]).reset_index()
```

Gives you:

```
  col1 col2 col3  col4
0    a    b  x_2   0.2
1    c    d  x_3   0.2
2    e    f  x_2   0.1
3    v    x  x_2   0.2
4    x    r  NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Series.last_valid_index` will help you greatly. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html#pandas.Series.last_valid_index